# Record and Speak at the same time using Twilio

Tags: python, asynchronous, concurrency, twilio, voice

I am currently developing a Python Flask application that utilizes Twilio, and I am encountering the following challenge:

- The application needs to **maintain continuous listening** capabilities to transcribe the user's speech into text.
- Once the user finishes speaking, the application should accurately repeat what the user has said. However, **it must also remain attentive to any additional input from the user**, allowing it to **promptly cease repeating if the user interrupts**.

In simpler terms, I'm seeking a way to have TwiML instructions run concurrently like :

```
response = VoiceResponse()
response.say(text)
```

```
response = VoiceResponse()
response.gather(input='speech', action=URL)
```

However, it appears that Twilio follows a **linear execution of its TwiML document**. Any guidance on how to work around this issue would be greatly appreciated. Thank you in advance for your assistance!